# Tables not created using Envers, without errors in compilation

Tags: c#, nhibernate-envers

I try create the tables with following code:

```
    protected override void PostProcessMappings(Configuration config)
    {
        base.PostProcessMappings(config);
        var enversConf = new NHibernate.Envers.Configuration.Fluent.FluentConfiguration();

        config.Properties.Add("nhibernate.envers.audit_table_prefix", string.Empty); // default
        config.Properties.Add("nhibernate.envers.audit_table_suffix", "_REV"); // default _AUD
        config.Properties.Add("nhibernate.envers.revision_field_name", "REV"); // default
        config.Properties.Add("nhibernate.envers.revision_type_field_name", "REVTYPE"); // default

        config.IntegrateWithEnvers(enversConf);

        new SchemaExport(config).Create(false, true);
     }
```

But in the schema, i cant see the tables.

I try to implement the code using [here](http://www.primordialcode.com/blog/post/nhibernate-envers-quick-introduction) (Test). Next, i debug and the nhibernate object: `Cfg.NHibernate.Configuration config` and in my project i cant catch the mappings, and in the test, i see the mapping that will be created.

I dont know what next i need to do.

Comment: Have you configured what entities you want to audit somewhere? (enversConf.Audit<YourEntityType>())